# Count Records Returned MySQL Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

How do I check the number of records returned from a search of my MySQL database 
with a statement like this:

```
$searchKey = 'Something to search for'; 
$searchResults = Doctrine::getTable('TableName')->createQuery('t')- 
    >where('columnName LIKE ?','%'.$searchKey.'%')->execute();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

maybe

```
$searchResults->rowCount();
```

from [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/Doctrine_Adapter_Statement_Mock/1_0#method_rowcount)

Comment: Just a side note : Doctrine Collection are implementing Iterator and ArrayAccess, so you can use count(), foreach() ... etc

Answer (score 6):

Wouldn't

`Doctrine::getTable('TableName')->createQuery('t')

->where('columnName LIKE ?','%'.$searchKey.'%')
->execute()
->rowCount();`

fetch the results from the database?

In that case,

`Doctrine::getTable('TableName')->createQuery('t')

->where('columnName LIKE ?','%'.$searchKey.'%')
->count()`

be a better solution?